# jQuery & AJAX: preventDefault on link, run AJAX request, then follow that link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, preventdefault

I have this presumably 'simple' task that is absolutely kicking my butt.

My aim is that when a user clicks a link, I prevent the default, run an ajax function on it, then follow that link (ie. resume default). The only thing I can get to work is capturing the href of the link and then following using window.location - this is not ideal, as it doesn't detect whether a user has opted to open in a new window/tab or in the same window/tab; also I think there must be a better way.

However what is happening is that the default is prevented, AJAX function is run but the link is not then followed. What I'm asking is: how to simulated the link click *after* the function has run?

**HTML**

```
<a href="some_href" data-id="789">This is the link</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e, options){

  // setup our options
  options = options || {};

  // get some details from the link
  var this_href = $(this).attr('href');
  var this_id = $(this).data('id');

  // if options aren't set and this link has a data-id attribute
  if(!options.stuff_done && $(this_id).length){

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent link following

    // run some ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: myAjax.ajax_url,
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        action : 'a_php_function',
        post_id : this_id
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // do stuff
      }).then(function(){
        $(this).trigger('click', { stuff_done: true });
      });

  } else {
    // else if it doesn't have a data-id, do default
  }
});
```

*Context:* Checking if a value ('data-id') is in an array using PHP/AJAX and if it is, removing it. This data-id relates to a post's ID in Wordpress, and needs to be removed when a user follows a link to that post.

Hence - user clicks link, data-id is checked, removed/not-removed from array, link is followed.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the default action when somebody uses middle-click or the right-click menu to open a link in another tab or window. So your original solution is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Edited to explicitly ask question. Thanks @JayBlanchard.

Comment: Ah, it looks like window.location could be the best and possibly only way to go, then. Thanks @jeroen.

Answer (score 1):

First give your href an ID like so:

`<a href="some_href" data-id="789" id='#some-link'>This is the link</a>`

Then simulate a click of it in your ajax success part:

```
...
success: function(response) {
    $('#some-link').click();
})
...
```

You can examine the `response` before triggering the click. Also, I don't think you need the `.then` and all that.

Comment: Slightly modified this as I have many links related to different articles (unique data-ids) on the same page. I added the data-id to the end of the #id as a modifier and then simulated a click on that element. 

Strangely this seems to fire before the PHP function has time to work it's magic. I think I will use 'window.location' and set that to the href of the clicked link.